# Search approach, splitting up joins into multiple queries?

Tags: mysql, join

I was looking for some arguments why splitting up joins into single queries would be better / worse then running a single query with all joins at once. I am working in a PHP / MySQL environment.

Assuming all tables have their indexes configured properly, I am convinced multiple queries will be slower then a single query.

Anyway, as I am looking for pro's and con's, I will list below what I have found and would be very interested in other people their feedback.

Single query:

[pro] Mysql is able to optimize the query

[pro] Less network traffic

[pro] Easier sorting and limiting results, using mysql

[pro] MySQL can do what it is good at

[con] Big queries

Multiple queries:

[pro] Smaller queries

[con] Need to loop over huge resultsets when narrowing down the results (PHP)

[con] Pagination becomes a pain

[con] More complex code needed in PHP

My feeling says that single queries are better/faster but maybe it depends on the situation as well. The tables are simple, we have some parent/child joins and some matching queries on cross tables as well. The biggest table is about 200k records.

Another thought that brought me here was that MySQL joins are OK when it is about filtering records but when you have for example a product and a product type then the product type will be loaded with another mechanism that will cache all producttypes for example, this way you dont need to join on the product type as well.

Comment: There is no question whatsoever that you should, where possible, perform joining/grouping/filtering/sorting operations in the database layer (for the reasons that you have highlighted).  I don't see the "size" of the query a material point of consideration (not least since it is traded against the "size" of the code in your application layer, which will often be considerably greater).

Comment: Thanks. If you are pointing at the PHP code when saying "database layer" I totally agree with you. Are there more considerations you could think of to split the joins or perform single queries beside the ones you provided above? It is also a matter of convincing myself which approach to use. Thanks for your clear answer.

Comment: No, by "database layer" I mean that which is run inside the RDBMS (MySQL): i.e. your SQL.  By "application layer" I mean that which is run in your application environment: i.e. your PHP.  No, there are no considerations whatsoever: always do it in the database layer if possible.

Comment: Agree and thanks, I have my answer.